# Need help writing my first script (LM-Sensors Custom Output)

Tags: scripting, sensors

I'm new here and to UNIX and Gnu/Linux scripts, I need help to build a script that modifies the lm-sensors output. 
When I use the command `sensors` this is the current output

```
mint@desktop:~$ sensors
amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:       +0.72 V
fan1:        1245 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 2400 RPM)
edge:         +37.0°C  (crit = +94.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       34.26 W  (cap = 145.00 W)
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +39.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +36.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +40.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:        +35.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:        +37.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

I'm coming from Windows and I used to have HWMonitor to see in real time stuff like usage and temps but it's hard to get this task on linux, my script idea is to make something that takes the sensors information and translates a friendly output to something like this:

```
amdgpu-pci-0100
Voltage:     +0.72 V 
Fans Speed:  1248 RPM ( Percentage %% )
Temperature: +36.0°C  ( Percentage %% )
Power:       34.22 W  ( Percentage %% )
GPU Usage:   Percentage %%
VRAM Usage:  1GB / 8GB ( Percentage %% )
```

Can you help me? I'm not asking the full script just any advice that you might have for a newbie, is this script possible to be made?

Btw, I  have tried PSensor but it doesn't show amdgpu module and RadeonTop dont show temps and VRAM.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the _exact_ output of `sensors` so we know what to look for. Use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. That said, this really is a bit too broad for us. Of course the script can be written, start looking into some basic "bash scripting" and also look at the command `grep`. Also, there are loads of tools that do this sort of thing (of course, sensors is one of them), have a look at `conky`, for example, but I'm sure there are GUI tools as well. Have you tried searching?

Comment: Hello @terdon I included the entire sensors output formated as code, I'll take a look into the basic bash scripting and grep. I have searched through the web for days looking for a HWMonitor replacement, all my research showed that there are GUI tools but they only work well on Nvidia cards because of their driver, its being super difficult to find a complete hardware monitor for amdgpu so I'm trying to build my own.

Comment: @terdon thank you for fixing the post I didn't noticed the mistakes

Comment: Does Ksysguard do what you need. It is a graphical system monitor. It is also customizable.

Comment: Hello @ctrl-alt-delor I've tried but it doesn't provide information about GPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AMD gpus, you can access all of this data as a simple user from `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/`

What you're looking for is `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/gpu_busy_percent`
It could be different from card0 (depending how many gpus you have)

In this directory you'll have everything your need as GPU/VRAM usage, temperature, tension and so on..

Most of files are safe to cat however NEVER cat `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/remove` and if you do, just reboot.

I strongly recommend to you to read this, the following is just a summary:
 https://dri.freedesktop.org/docs/drm/gpu/amdgpu.html#gpu-power-thermal-controls-and-monitoring

This is a list of file which are safe to cat.
`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/gpu_busy_percent` GPU Core usage in %
`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/mem_busy_percent` GPU Mem usage in %

All files prefixed with `pp_` are readable except `pp_table`.
`pp_dpm_*` are related to GPU core and memory clocks
`pp_dpm_sclk` is for the GPU core
`pp_dpm_mclk` is for the GPU memory
The current state is marqued with a `*`

Under the directory `hwmon` you will have another directory corresponding to your hardward monitor for me it is named `hwmon0`, here are

`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/fan*` GPU Fan current/min/max
`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/in*` GPU mV  and label
`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/power*` GPU Watt current/min/max
`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/pwm*` GPU PWM current/min/max/
`/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon0/temp*` GPU temp current/min/max

Comment: Hello I found good information there but I'm afraid to damage my gpu because I cant "cat" or "ls" anything there without sudo, watch command is not allowed either. I moved from Linux Mint now I'm using Debian.

Comment: You will not damage your GPU while you are not trying to overide it's configuration.
Cat will display the content of the file without modifying it, however there are two file you should avoid to cat `remove` and `rescan`. I'll add more info in my answer

Comment: Wow thank you so much for that update, I was playing with cat on every file I found, your answer is exactly what I needed

Comment: You're welcome :)